# How Can I Find Last Entered Record

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: attendees & history. History table is where I post payments for all the attendees. It also stores an historyid and the attendeeid. The query I'm using to try to get to the last record entered in the history table for a particular attendee is:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT a.fname, a.lname, h.amount, h.subsidy, h.last_payment, h.balance 
                        FROM history AS h
                        INNER JOIN  
                        attendees AS a
                        ON a.attendeeid = h.attendeeid
                        WHERE a.attendeeid = :id
                        ORDER BY historyid DESC LIMIT 1)');
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But the code is failing to return anything at all. Since there will likely be historyid's greater than the one I'm trying to retrieve, how do I associate the greatest historyid for that attendee so I get the last record entered for them in the History table? What I'm using is obviously not the answer. Thanks in advance for your help.

Sorry. The schemas are:

`TABLE attendees (
  attendeeid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  lname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  dojid varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  address1 varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  address2 varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  city varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  state char(2) NOT NULL,
  zipcode varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  phonenumber varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  memberid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (attendeeid),
  KEY memberid (memberid),
  CONSTRAINT attendees_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (memberid) REFERENCES members (memberid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

TABLE `history` (
  `historyid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` float NOT NULL,
  `subsidy` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `last_payment` date NOT NULL,
  `amount_paid` float NOT NULL,
  `balance` float NOT NULL,
  `attendeeid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `memberid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`historyid`),
  KEY `attendeeid` (`attendeeid`),
  CONSTRAINT `history_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`attendeeid`) REFERENCES `attendees` (`attendeeid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Just a comment: What's the point of having ``ORDER BY historyid DESC`` when you have ``LIMIT 1``?

Comment: Just an answer, so he gets the highest id which is the first id when you order DESCENDING

Comment: Your table schema would help, we are not psychic.

Comment: sometimes I think that some of us ARE psychic, but I'm not

Answer (score 0):

Please can you provide the structure of both tables? I'm guessing your tables contains a date columns, or something like that.

Anyway, I would try something like:

```
select * 
from (select a.attendeeid,max(h.id) 
      FROM history AS h INNER JOIN attendees AS a ON a.attendeeid = h.attendeeid
      group by a.attendeeid) as maxHistoryPerAttendee
```

In that way, you will have the maximun history id per each attendeeid. I'm guessing the max id, is the last inserted row.

Comment: To flag or not to flag. I see where you're coming from so I'll let it pass.

Comment: Thanks, Perimosh. That's the ticket right there. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually, that gets me the max(historyid). When I try to get the last_payment from that same row, it returns the last_payment from the very first historyid row entered for that attendee instead of the max(historyid) row.

Comment: To flag or not to flag? What do you mean? I'll let it pass?

Comment: Try max(last_payment). Doing that, and grouping by attendeeid, will give you the max date for payment column.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query with a couple fields added:

      `select * 
      from (select a.attendeeid,max(h.historyid),fname,lname,last_payment,amount
      FROM history AS h INNER JOIN attendees AS a ON a.attendeeid = h.attendeeid
      group by a.attendeeid) as maxHistoryPerAttendee
where attendeeid = 29`

In doing that, I got the first-row entry for that attendee's last_payment instead of the last_payment associated with the MAX(historyid) row.

To add to this and call it done, I got this to work. It's very near my original query.

`$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT  fname, lname, amount, subsidy, last_payment, balance, a.attendeeid, h.historyid
                    FROM history AS h 
                    INNER JOIN attendees AS a ON a.attendeeid = h.attendeeid
                    where h.attendeeid = :id
                    ORDER BY h.historyid DESC LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();`

Works like a champ!